# Using resource attributes as variable in Terraform templates

Tags: consul, terraform

I'm trying to use the attributes of an EC2 instance as a variable, but it keeps failing or otherwise not working.  As you can see below, I want to insert the private IP of the instance into a config file that will get copied to the instance.  The remote-exec script will then move the file into place (/etc/vault.d/server-config.json)

**instances.tf**

```
resource "template_file" "tpl-vault-server-config" {
    template = "${file("${path.module}/templates/files/vault-server-config.json.tpl")}"      
    vars {
        aws_private_ip = "${aws_instance.ec2-consul-server.private_ip}"
    }  
}

provisioner "file" {
    source = "${template_file.tpl-vault-server-config.rendered}"
    destination = "/tmp/vault-server-config.json"
}
```

**vault-server-config.json.tpl**

```
backend "consul" {
    address = "127.0.0.1:8500"
    path = "vault"
    tls_enable = 1
    tls_ca_file = "/etc/consul.d/ssl/ca.cert"
    tls_cert_file = "/etc/consul.d/ssl/consul.cert"
    tls_key_file = "/etc/consul.d/ssl/consul.key"
}

listener "tcp" {
    address = "${aws_private_ip}:8200"
    tls_cert_file = "/etc/consul.d/ssl/consul.cert"
    tls_key_file = "/etc/consul.d/ssl/consul.key"   
}
```

The error on `terraform plan` is:

```
* aws_instance.ec2-consul-server: missing dependency: template_file.tpl-vault-server-config
```

Questions:

- Am I taking the wrong approach?
- Am I missing something basic?
- How do you get an instance's attributes into a file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your `ec2-consul-server` definition? It looks like you've possibly got a circular dependency order here if your `aws_instance` relies on the `provisioner` which in turn relies on the `template file`... which then relies on the `aws_instance`

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I was defining the template_file resource within the current resource and this was part of the problem.  When I fixed that, things worked much easier.